# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (110,110,1)

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to draw a square in my image. I saw this process in an youtube video.
Here's the code:

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import img_as_float
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = io.imread("imagem.jpg")
print(img.min(), img.max())
print(img)
img[90:200, 90:200, 1:2] = [0, 255, 0]
#plt.imshow(img)
```

The error:

> in .
> img[90:200, 90:200, 1:2] = [0, 255, 0].
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,) into shape (110,110,1)

I read a similar error here in stackoverflow, but wasn't abble to fix my code.

The image i'm reading:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhhDS.png)

I was expecting to draw a square in the image.

Answer (score 1):

It's `imp[90:200, 90:200] = [0, 255, 0]`. Since you want to override all three color-components of those pixels with `[0, 255, 0]` (effectively painting a solid green square), there is no need to specify the third index.

Just so you understand how indexing works, if you wanted to adjust only the green component of those pixels, the code would be `imp[90:200, 90:200, 1] = 255`.